# How can I load a new RecycleView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I need a help! I'm using `RecycleView` with Retrofit my service is already returning a `JSON` and I'm already displaying everything correctly.

But when I click on any item I want to reload this `recycleview` with other data.

What better to open a new activity with this data or develop a routine to reload this same recycleview with the data from the other service?

If second best solution is how can I do this?

What I want to do is exactly the same videos below, but using recycleview and retrofit because it is new components.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvlhc_THCY8

```
public class TeleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TeleAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<Tele> Tele;
private Context context;

public TeleAdapter(List<Tele> Tele, Context context){
    this.Tele = Tele;
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.Tele_categoria_item, parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.Name.setText(Tele.get(position).getName());
    holder.Email.setText(Tele.get(position).getUrl());
    final String music = Tele.get(position).getUrl();


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    try {
        return Tele.size();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Tele.size();
}


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView Name,Email;
    String music;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        Email = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.email);


        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });

    }
}
}
```

Comment: use visibility on same activity with two recyclerviews when you click on first recyclerview item then hide first one recyclerview and show second one.

Comment: And when the user clicks the back button? I'll need to check this out, too.
I think the best alternative is to have 2 fragment with 2 same recycleview.

Comment: yes you can do this try it then share your code will help you

Answer (score 0):

You have to take in mind some things:

1. If the model is always the same, you could use the same adapter. If not, you need to create both and the change the active adapter in the `RecyclerView`.
2. If you need to get the first list again, you should split the information in different `RecyclerView` to make this easy. Could be in different fragments or activities, as you want depending on the app flow.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this method to your TeleAdapter

```
public void setData(ArrayList<Tele> tele) {
    this.tele = tele;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And after getting new data call something like this

```
yourInstanceOfTeleAdapter.setData(newTeleData)
```

PS: it is very bad idea to use first capitalized letter for variable names! Use small letter instead.

```
private List<Tele> tele;
```